# Strange result of LaplaceTransform

Tags: special-functions, integral-transforms

I mean

```
LaplaceTransform[BesselI[3, x], x, s] // Simplify
```

> `Piecewise[{{1 - 4*s^2, s < 1}, {((-s + Sqrt[-1 + s^2])*(1 - 2*s^2 + 2*s*Sqrt[-1 + s^2]))/ Sqrt[-1 + s^2], s > 1}}, 0]`

which is in discordance with

```
NIntegrate[Exp[-1/2 x]*BesselI[3, x], {x, 0, Infinity}]
```

> `1.969025342284566*10^315`

In fact, the integral `Integrate[Exp[-s* x]*BesselI[3, x], {x, 0, Infinity}]` diverges for `s>0,s<1`, as

```
Normal[Series[BesselI[3, x], {x, Infinity, 1}]]
```

> `-((I E^-x)/(Sqrt[2 \[Pi]] Sqrt[x])) + E^x/(Sqrt[2 \[Pi]] Sqrt[x])`

shows. Of course, the values of the Laplace transform under consideration for such values of `s` are not of importance in view of the definition of `InverseLaplaceTransform`. However, I am interested in the way Mathematica 12.2 produces `1 - 4*s^2`.

Addition. A similar issue in 12.3 on Cloud

```
BilateralLaplaceTransform[BesselJ[3,x],x,s]
```

> `0 if Re[s] ≤ 0`

Comment: Try: `Limit[Integrate[BesselI[3, x] Exp[-s*x]*Exp[-e*x], {x, 0, Infinity}, 
    Assumptions -> {0 < s < 1, e >= 0}][[1]], e -> 0, 
  Assumptions -> {0 < s < 1}] // Expand`

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk: This results in `1 - 4 s^2 + (3 I s)/Sqrt[1 - s^2] - (4 I s^3)/Sqrt[1 - s^2]`, not `1-4*s^2`.

Comment: Real part is: `1-4*s^2` .

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk:  So what?

Comment: `Integrate[BesselI[3, x] Exp[-s*x]*Exp[-e*x], {x, 0, Infinity}, 
 Assumptions -> {0 < s < 1, e >= 0}]` performs `ConditionalExpression[(4*e^3 - 3*s + 4*s^3 + 
   Sqrt[-1 + e^2 + 2*e*s + s^2] - 
   4*s^2*Sqrt[-1 + e^2 + 2*e*s + s^2] - 
   4*e^2*(-3*s + Sqrt[-1 + e^2 + 2*e*s + s^2]) + 
   e*(-3 + 12*s^2 - 8*s*Sqrt[-1 + e^2 + 2*e*s + s^2]))/
  Sqrt[-1 + e^2 + 2*e*s + s^2], e > 0 && (e > 1 || e + s > 1)]`.

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk:  You don't present the condition `e > 0 && (e > 1 || e + s > 1`.

Answer (score 1):

The result of Mathematica is correct. The Laplace transform `LaplaceTransform[BesselI[3, x], x, s] // Simplify`
is not found as a diveregent improper integral, but in the sense of generalized
functions (=distributions). As [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform) says,
"Thus, extending the Fourier transform to the complex domain means
it includes the Laplace transform as a special case—the case of causal functions—but with the change of variable $s = 2\pi i \xi$".
I haven't got at hand the definition of the Laplace transform of a generalized function,
so I refer to the one for  the Fourier transform (see the linked Wiki article).

Making use of the opportunity, I'd like to turn again to
[a similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4341830/possible-bug-laplacetransform-in-mathematica).
Here Mathematica is right too. Indeed, `Exp[-x^2]*DiracDelta[x - 2] == DiracDelta[-2 + x]/E^4` and this is not in contradiction with   formula (5) in section 6.15 of W. Rudin, Functional Analysis.
I found the correct explanation in a book
Шубин М.А. Лекции об уравнениях математической физики.-2-е изд., испр.-М.:МЦНМО, 2003. - 303 с.
ISBN 5-900916-97-9 on p. 85 (see examples 4.11 and 4.12 [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rliyx8a9jofwmy9/%D0%97%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BA%20%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%202022-01-29%2010.14.38.png?dl=0)). I think a book https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A1458.35001 is close to it.
The explanation is not simple and obvious and is far away of the attempt to answer by Bill Watts. BTW, example 4.12 in the Shubin's book demonstrates the inconvenience of the notation $\delta(x)$.

Comment: Well, those of us who actually *use* Dirac δ as a tool for solving practical problems find δ(x) convenient and transparent. And we find `Exp[-x^2]*DiracDelta[x - 2] == DiracDelta[-2 + x]/E^4` obvious. Sampling a function at a point only tells you the value at the point.